# list view recycling using base adapter

Tags: android

i am having a list view with an RelativeLayout in it. i want to add a view in that Relative Layout on click of that RelativeLayout..here is the code

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(convertView==null)
        {
            holder=new ViewHolder_CurrentMatches();
            convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_matches, null);
            holder.firstTeamLogoLayout=(RelativeLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.createLeague_firstTeamLogoLayout);
            holder.wheel=new View(context);//The View i want to Add
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder=(ViewHolder_CurrentMatches)convertView.getTag();
        }

            setOnClick(holder.firstTeamLogoLayout,holder.wheel);


        return convertView;
    }

        private void setOnClick(final RelativeLayout view1,final View w)
    {
        view1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                doThings(view1,w);
            }
        });
    }
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private void doThings(RelativeLayout view1,RelativeLayout view2,final WheelView w)
    {
        params1=new LayoutParams(view1.getMeasuredWidth()-10,view1.getMeasuredHeight()/2);
        params1.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
        w.setLayoutParams(params1);
        view1.addView(w);
        view1.setClickable(false);  
    }
```

my class extends the BaseAdapter as an adapter..

problem is that when i scroll the view then the view already attached on the position i did not click..which is done by list view recycling..
please give me a solution so that i can have proper working Class.